# Change a value with a drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an `iFrame` that I need to change just one parts of the elements value

```
iframe src="http://www.twitch.tv/USERNAME"/
```

So the idea is that the user will select a name from a dropdown list and that will change the iFrame `USERNAME` to the correct user name:

So:

> - Steve is selected in drop down list.
> - Page reloads with the iFrame now having `src="http://www.twitch.tv/STEVESUSERNAME/"`

What would also be cool is if the page did not have to reload and only the `iFrame` had to reload.

Thank you

Comment: you need to use .on('change') for select list and get value with .val()  and then change the iframe src  with .attr('src', new_url);  .. make a little search you will find ton of examples .. Good Luck

Comment: What's your relevant HTML?

Comment: @DavidThomas I am building the page right now so the only html is this the select tag and an iframe tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to change source of "CasterChat" iframe only? You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Caster').on('change', function(){
        $('#CasterChat').attr('src', 'http://www.twitch.tv/' + $('#Caster').val() + '/chat?popout=');
    });
});
```

Don't forget to load jQuery to make this work.

Comment: Hey Pisamce. Here is what I have done: http://30dayslater.net/demo/chat.html What am I missing?

Comment: You are running script before your page is loaded. You should wait until DOM is loaded, then tun the code. I have updated the code in my answer, it will create event listener after your page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$('#Caster').change(function() {
  var value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  $('#CasterChat').attr('src', 'http://.../' + encodeURIComponent(value));
});
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, I can not seem to understand how to work this into my code, here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjZpRp The iFrame with the id "CasterChat" is the frame that is going to change

Comment: @RichardReynolds try something like this.